# there's no question mark printing before query params

Tags: url, axios, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, urlsearchparams

first way I tried is :

```
  static async callSendApi(requestBody) {
    let url = new URL(
      
        `${API_URL}/${PAGE_ID}/messages`
      
    );
    url.search = new URLSearchParams({
      access_token: `${PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    });
    console.warn("Request body is\n" + JSON.stringify(requestBody));
    let response = await axios.post(url, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
      // access_token: `${PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      consoleconst`Unable to call Send API: ${response.statusText}`,
        await response.json();
    }
  }
```

Second way I tried is :

```
 static async callSendApi(requestBody) {
    let url = new URL(
      `${API_URL}/${PAGE_ID}/messages?access_token=${PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
    );
    /* url.search = new URLSearchParams({
      access_token: `${PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    });*/
    console.warn("Request body is\n" + JSON.stringify(requestBody));
    let response = await axios.post(url, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
      // access_token: `${PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      consoleconst`Unable to call Send API: ${response.statusText}`,
        await response.json();
    }
  }
```

the error I get :

```
 error: { 
    message: 'Unknown path components: /messagesaccess_token=access_token
    type: 'OAuthException',
    code: 2500,
    fbtrace_id: 'AbBJGVotjz3ijKKLzVE6_CM'
    }
```

I'm receiving this error in both ways. both ways are escaping the '?' mark. I have no idea what is happening.. I'm using heroku for this. I tried deleting and redeploying the repository to confirm if the code is not updating. but still gives this error. :( .

Comment: Did you tried with the `curl` command? What is the response?

Comment: Anyway your first code snippet worked for me.

My Versions:

 - Node: 16.17.1
 - Axios: 1.1.2

Comment: axios.post(...) should be corrected as `const response = await axios.post(url, requestBody, {headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json"}});`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried withot using URL and URLSearchParams and it worked!

below is my code:

```
static async callSendApi(requestBody) {
 
    console.warn("Request body is\n" + JSON.stringify(requestBody));

    let response = await axios.post(
      `${API_URL}/${PAGE_ID}/messages`,
      {
        params: { access_token: `${PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}` },
      },
      {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
        
      }
    );
    if (!response.ok) {
      consoleconst`Unable to call Send API: ${response.statusText}`,
        await response.json();
    }
  }
```